# Adding value from multiple select option to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, mootools, joomla2.5

I have 2 seletboxes

```
<select id="field1" class="inputtextbox  required" size="0">
<option value="Student">Student</option>
<option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
<option value="Director">Director</option>
</select>

<select id="field2" class="inputtextbox  required" size="0">
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
</select>
```

and I have an empty INPUT field

```
<input name="title" type="text" id="title" value="">
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is:

Now when I select for example a option from the first selectbox, for example I select "Student", the text "Student" is copied to the INPUT value, then for example I select an option from the second selectbox, let's say 2001, now this must be added to the INPUT value too..

I have made this but it's not working quite right, the code I made adds the select option value to the input but it deletes the other values from other select options that were added to the input..

```
jQuery('#field1').on('change', function () {
      jQuery("input[name='title']").val(jQuery( "#field1" ).val());
});
```

So this code works, but it works only for ONE select option, for example if the code is like this:

```
jQuery('#field1').on('change', function () {
      jQuery("input[name='title']").val(jQuery( "#field1" ).val());
});
jQuery('#field2').on('change', function () {
      jQuery("input[name='title']").val(jQuery( "#field2" ).val());
});
```

Now for example I select "Student" from the "field1" selectbox, and select "2001" from the "field2" selectbox, the value of input must be "Student 2001", instead the input contains only ONE of the selected values "Student" or "2001" .. depending on which is last selected...

Can somebody help me to achieve so the input value has all 2 selected options please?

Thank you

UPDATE

With the help of "bipen" the code work like this now:

```
jQuery('#field1').on('change', function () {
jQuery("input[name='title']").val(jQuery( "#field1" ).val() + ' ' + jQuery( "#field2" ).val());
});

jQuery('#field2').on('change', function () {
jQuery("input[name='title']").val(jQuery( "#field1" ).val() + ' ' + jQuery( "#field2" ).val());
});
```

I had to put the values to both codes because user can select a value from the second selectbox not necessarily from the first..

Wondering, is there any way to make this code less and cleaner... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
jQuery('#field1').on('change', function () {

  jQuery("#title").val(jQuery("#field1").val());
});

jQuery('#field2').on('change', function () {
  var val=jQuery("#title").val();
  jQuery("#title").val(val + ' ' +jQuery( "#field2" ).val());
});
```

or

using `this` reference

```
  jQuery('#field1').on('change', function () {

  jQuery("#title").val(jQuery(this).val());
});

jQuery('#field2').on('change', function () {
  var val=jQuery("#title").val();
  jQuery("#title").val(val + ' ' +jQuery(this).val());
});
```

since you have an id of the input use id selector...easy and readable..

Comment: I have added your code like this, and it seems to work thank you :)

Comment: Could you please check my UPDATE and give me your thoughts please? Thank you

Comment: if user selects from second and then from first...what should be the valu in input??

Answer (score 1):

You can try following.

```
  var selectedField1 = "";
    jQuery('#field1').on('change', function () {
        jQuery("#title").val(jQuery("#field1").val());
        selectedField1 = jQuery("#field1").val();
    });

    jQuery('#field2').on('change', function () {
        var val = selectedField1
        jQuery("#title").val(val + ' ' + jQuery("#field2").val());
    });
```

In this code, it will prevent to add multiple values of field2 into input.

Here's the filddle...[example](http://jsfiddle.net/WRwBN/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 jQuery('#field1').on('change', function () {
      jQuery("input[name='title']").val(jQuery( "#field1" ).val());
 });

 jQuery('#field2').on('change', function () {
      jQuery("input[name='title']").val(jQuery("input[name='title']").val() + ' ' + jQuery("#field2" ).val());
 });
```